# Send HTTP Request to Apple Music

Tags: javascript, itunes

I'm playing around to add music to Apple Music. I record the request with "*Charles*" and can add it to my library again after I deleted it after I click *repeat selected request*. Is it possible to send request with javascript? I tried it with song title 368207161 but it doesn't work

```
    var headers = {
    'X-Apple-Private-Listening':'false',
    'X-Apple-Store-Front':'143445-2,32',
    'Client-iTunes-Sharing-Version':'3.15',
    'Accept-Language':'en-GB;q=1.0, de-AT;q=0.9',
    'Client-Cloud-DAAP-Version':'1.3/iTunes-12.9.0.164',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip',
    'X-Apple-itre':'0',
    'Content-Length':'77',
    'Client-DAAP-Version':'3.13',
    'User-Agent':'iTunes/12.9 (Macintosh; OS X 10.14) AppleWebKit/606.1.36.1.9 (dt:1)',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-dmap-tagged',
    'X-Dsid':'<value deleted>',
    'X-Guid':'<value deleted>',
    'Cookie':'<value deleted>'
 };
        var myRequest = new Request("https://ld-5.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZDaap.woa/daap/databases/1/cloud-add","POST",headers,"368207161");
        var exchange = httpClient.send(myRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. This internal API is not intended for web use, and does not allow cross-domain requests.

If you want to allow users to add music to their Apple Music account, use an embedded Apple Music player. You can create these embeds using the [Apple Music Toolbox](https://tools.applemusic.com/en-us).

Comment: Does it work with python or any other programming language to send requests?

Comment: Does what work? The Apple Music embed is a web interface. It's not intended for use outside a browser.

Comment: I‘m not sure if that is correct because i‘m able to send a request with Charles. And this has nothing to do with an API.